# Olympiad number theory problem with primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find all pairs of $x, y \in \mathbb Z$ that satisfy the following equation:
$$1 + 1996x+1998y=xy$$
(Irish Mathematical Olympiad 1997)

I am stuck and I have not been able to make even a start to a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I presume 1997 being a prime and being omitted in the question has something to do with the solution but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Are $x,y\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Hint: Are you familiar with Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick?

Comment: *Complete the product* as in the linked dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque  Hello, after applying SFFT/Completing the product I am left with $(x-1998)(y-1996)=1+1998*1996=3988009$ and I am wondering how one would efficiently find the factor pairs especially in an Olympiad setting where time would be an issue.

Comment: $1+(n+1)(n-1)$ easily factors. $\ \ $

Comment: Thank you, I had not taught of that.